# add filters in configServer

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, filter

With this architecture, i created a configServer that point to git repository where all my configurations are stored

[image]

Now, i want to secure this configurations because it contains a critic information (as servers, passwords, ...etc.)

So, to do that i fount [this](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cloud-securing-services)

By adding the dependency `spring-boot-starter-security` to the configServer, then defining user, password in the `application.properties` my configuration's files are now protected by Basic Authentication

[image]

Now, i must share my user/password to every client `bootstrap.yml` so they can fetch configurations from configServer

```
spring.cloud.config.uri: http://localhost:8888
spring.application.name: ws-config
spring.profiles.active: default
spring.cloud.config.label: local_dev
spring.cloud.config.username: user
spring.cloud.config.password: password
```

This work perfectly for me, now every micro-service can fetch it's own configuration by the authentication `user, password`

Now, i want to do this in an other way (if possible)

Defining a security in configServer (only in configServer) by filters or cross-origins, so the goal is to not sharing any `user, password` with clients

So, something like this

```
config.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("http://localhost:8085", "http://localhost:8081", "http://localhost:8080")); //mean only this links can fetch configurations from configServer
```

Comment: CORS is strictly a browser protection feature. It is entirely circumvented by any service-to-service communication.

Comment: ok, i understand, so is there any other way to protect my configServer without sharing any user password ?

Comment: You could add an authentication filter in the security config and just check ip’s/hostnames of the request

Comment: @123 can give me a simple example how to do this please!